# using loops stops implementation of other pieces of code

Tags: java, loops, user-interface

im am trying to make pong by only using by y current knowledge , but now I'm at a halt , i want to move the ball , for that i need to change the variables `BallX` and `BallY` in a while loop bu the problem is that is i use the `while(true){                  }` to do something , my implementation of the GUI is stopped , eventually doing nothing and entering a infinite loop. How can i solve this problem.

this is the code , don't mind the unused variables

```
package pong;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;

import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class gamePanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener , KeyListener{
int fixPlayerYPos_one = 25;
int fixPlayerYPos_two = 930;
int playerPos_one = 200;
int playerPos_two = 200;
int PlayerDimenX = 25;
int PlayerDimenY = 200;
int BallXElement = 1;
int BallYElement = 2;
int ballSpeed = 10;
int ballX = 490;
int ballY = 340;
Timer timer = new Timer(5, this);
gameGraphics player_one = new gameGraphics(fixPlayerYPos_one, playerPos_one, PlayerDimenX,                   
PlayerDimenY, Color.cyan);
gameGraphics player_two = new gameGraphics(fixPlayerYPos_two, playerPos_two, PlayerDimenX, 
PlayerDimenY, Color.pink);
gameGraphics Ball = new gameGraphics(ballX, ballY, 20, 20, Color.yellow);
public gamePanel() {
    setSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
    setLayout(null);
    setOpaque(true);
    setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
    //panel contructor
    
    
}
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    
    super.paintComponent(g);
    
    player_one.drawSquare(g);
    player_two.drawSquare(g);
    Ball.drawSquare(g);
    
    
}
@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    
    
}
@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    
    
}
@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    
}
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    
    
}
}
```

there is also a gameGraphics class but i dint think it is related to the context of this question

Comment: Use a timer which fires every (say) 100ms and updates the positions of your objects.

Comment: e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59122102/java-swing-creating-animation-using-swing-timer

Comment: @tgdavies probably i am not able to get anything there , can you explain how can i update every 100ms without using a loop?

Comment: @tgdavies so am i correct that i should use something known as threads?

Comment: Maybe this is a better example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33487186/swing-timer-stopwatch-in-java